# How do I set a fixed background on all pages (for example, in the center of each page)

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays

How do I set a fixed background on all pages (for example, in the center of each page)

I want to place this background with the following code in the center of all pages

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \node[blue!45, 
        rotate = 30] at (3,-1.4) {
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[line width=0.2 mm] circle[radius=2 cm];
                \draw[line width=0.2 mm] circle[radius=1.95 cm];
                inner circles
                \draw[line width=0.2 mm]  circle[radius=1.3 cm]  ;
                \draw[line width=0.2 mm]  circle[radius=1.25 cm]  ;
                \path[
                postaction={
                    decoration={
                        text along path,,text color=blue!45,
                        text={                PROF~~ MEBKHOUTA 
                        },
                        text align=center,
                        reverse path
                    },
                    decorate
                }
                ]
                (10:1.5cm) arc (10:180:1.5cm); 
                \node[blue!30,rotate=-60] at (350:1.6cm) {$\bigstar$};
                \node[blue!30,rotate=60] at (190:1.6cm) {$\bigstar$};  
                \path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text color=blue!50, text align=fit to path,text={OUSSAMA}}}] (209:1.8cm) arc (209:330:1.8cm);
                 central text
                \node[font=\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont] at (0, 0){{ الرياضيات}};
            \end{tikzpicture} 
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}`
```

Comment: There is a % in the middle of your code which comments out half.

Comment: Also, you can't (or at least shouldn't) put a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture.

Comment: There is a package which can do this for you. However, I stopped using it in favour of a simpler method similar to @JohnKormylo's answer, though I don't remember why. (That is, save in a box and then `\put` in shipout.)

Answer (score 2):

I gave up trying to fix your tkizpicture.  I did check that [overlay] by itself will place the "cursor" on the origin.  However, the following will work even when the center is not at the origin.

There is a lot of overhead each time you create a tikzpicture, so I made one copy and put it into a savebox.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}% fkae text

\newsavebox{\background}
\savebox{\background}{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[draw, red] at (1,1) {Background};
 \coordinate (center) at (current bounding box.center);
 \pgfresetboundingbox
 \path(center);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put (0.5\paperwidth, -0.5\paperheight) {\usebox\background}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```